# How can i add IOS 14 support to my React Native app?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I know so many React Native Developers who were unable to run their application on ios 14 , i want to add how you will be able to support ios 14 with only a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your Podfiles located in ios/ folder of your project then use this code piece to provide support for minimum version of ***IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET*** into your RN app.

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
end
```